# Convert Excel custom date column in vb6

Tags: excel, vba, vb6, excel-dates

I have a vb6 code that read value from excel which is in mm-yy format . I want to convert it as dd-mm-yyyy format in my application

My vb6 code for reading column is

```
.Range(Purchase_Excel!ExpdateColumn & intLoopCounter)
```

where counter is the row number

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the column reader with the format function like this:

```
Format(.Range(Purchase_Excel!ExpdateColumn & intLoopCounter), "mmm yyyy")
```

Comment: the date in excel Sep-20

Comment: I want is as sept 2020

Comment: your suggestion return 20-sept-2019

Comment: Please check the edited answer. "mmm yyyy" should give you what you expect.

Comment: It work with Format(.Range(Purchase_Excel!ExpdateColumn & intLoopCounter).Text, "yy-mm-dd")

Comment: but the dd value is not exact as in excel

Comment: Can I get the value seen [exactly same ] in the Formula bar of Excel

Comment: 1) Decide what format do you need. You originally mentioned "dd-mm-yyyy" then "mmm yyyy" and now "yy-mm-dd". 2) Are you using Excel VBA or VB6?